# How to find the even numbers in my code?

Tags: java

for my assignment I have to write another method called numberOfEvens which takes in the array of my random int generator code and uses a for loop to traverse through the array. Thus making it count the number of elements in the array which are even then returns this number. How can I do this? Please give me an clear example thanks!

```
  public static int[] randomArray(int size) { 
  Random random =new Random();int[] a = new int[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = random.nextInt(100);

    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you know how to loop over an array and increment numbers. I think you're most of the way there!

Comment: Your question is either a homework question or a homework-like question, and in this situation this site requires that you always post with your question your best good-faith effort to solve the problem at hand and tell us *specifically* what problems you're having with your attempt, and in all honesty, you ***want*** to do this regardless of the site requirements. This is how you learn. Please improve this question by showing us this important attempt and description.

Comment: Here's a little help: An even number is one that divides by 2 exactly, specifically the remainder is zero after dividing by 2. Is there a way to make this test in code?

Comment: Do I smell a modulus?

Comment: I know that ex.(x&2==0) how is this done to find the random numbers in this code?

Comment: Please help me, this is vary important for me.

Comment: @A.Rahman try this to use an `if` statement inside the `for` loop. For the *condition*, try to **modulus** the number, to check if it is **even**.

Comment: I tried but it still did not work. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%` it will give you the remainder

Comment: Thanks I know, but I need to find all evens in those random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know if a number I even in math? Once you have this, test it inside your loop and make a value that increases every time this is true.

Comment: I tried this, but It seems to not work.

Comment: public static void numberOfEvens(String[] args){
a[i] = random.nextInt(100);
while (i % 2==0) { System.out.println(random[100]);
            i++;

Comment: @A.Rahman please post your code properly, it makes it easier to read. Anyhow, are you testing 'i' or 'a[I]'? are you printing the even numbers, counting them, or both?

Comment: I'm trying to find all of the even numbers in the random number code that I made.

Comment: @A.Rahman I forgot to mention, if your method is returning an int then your method should not be public static void

Comment: then what should it be?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] randomArray(int size) { 
    Random random =new Random();int[] a = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        if (a[i]%2==0)
            // The Number is even 
     }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to break it down into steps.

Here's some pseudocode (I'll leave it as an exercise to translate this to Java):

```
count = 0

for each integer in array:
   if integer is even:
      increment count
end for

return count
```

Comment: Like this? public static int numbersOfEvens(int[] a) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i]%2==0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

Comment: EJoshuaS, you rock!!!

Comment: @A.Rahman A little hard to read in the comments but that looks like the right idea